# Pass Range of Numbers Argument to Bash Script

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to pass a range of numbers (YYYYMMDD date) as an argument to a Bash script via the terminal:

```
time ./somescript.sh 201808{01..28}
```

This method is not working though and only passes "20180801" before quitting

Comment: It’s probably the script only using the first argument. Can you change it?

Comment: You need to show the contents of `somescript.sh`.

Comment: When the script only processes one parameter, you can time the 28 calls with `time (for d in 201808{01..28}; do ./somescript.sh "$d"; done)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
"$@"
```

in your script `./somescript.sh`, and not

```
"$1"
```